# how to dispatch an action to return default state

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux, react-redux

In a reducer function we usually return default state if it doesn't go to switch block.

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action: any): any {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_TYPE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        someBoolean: false
      });
  }

  return state;
}
```

I tried `dispatch(undefined, {type: undefined})` but I got error action may not have undefined type.

Is there a way that we could dispatch action which will return defalut state.

PS: Just trying a different way. Of-course we can have some action type and return default state.

Comment: By `deafult state` do you mean the initialState or current state from the store?

Comment: Where is the `dispatch` function?

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood you correctly, you want to reset your state to the initial value.

```
switch (action.type) {
  case SOME_TYPE:
    return Object.assign({}, state, {
      someBoolean: false
    });
  case 'DEFAULT':
    return initialState;
  default:
     return state;
}
```

Then simply dispatch it:

```
dispatch({ type: 'DEFAULT' });
```

**Note**: remember to add a `default` case inside your reducer.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if I'm getting this correctly, but to return your state simply do:

```js
function reducer(state = initialState, action: any): any {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_TYPE:
      return state;
  }

  return state;
}
```

Or to reset your initial state, do:

```js
function reducer(state = initialState, action: any): any {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_TYPE:
      return initialState;
  }

  return state;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use the action's paylaod to update the state, and you can check if you have any payload, use it, otherwise go back to initial state

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action: any): any {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_TYPE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        someBoolean: action.payload.someBoolean || initialState.someBoolean
      });
  }

  return state;
}
```

And dispatch an `undefined` :

```
dispatch({
  type: SOME_TYPE,
  payload: {
    someBoolean: undefined
  }
});
```

But a better way would be to have a `type` to revert back to `initialState`

```
function reducer(state = initialState, action: any): any {
  switch (action.type) {
    case SOME_TYPE:
      return Object.assign({}, state, {
        someBoolean: false
      });
    case REVERT:
      return initialState;
  }

  return state;
}
```